Explanation for proof of the continuity of the function in $t$ defined as the integral of a continuous function of two variables
Statement: Let $f:[a,b]\times\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, (x,t) \mapsto f(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Then
$$
F(t) := \int_a^b f(x,t)dx
$$
is continuous.
I understand the proof for this up until the last part where continuity of $F$ is shown.
Let $t_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and $r>0$ and let $\epsilon>0$. Since $f$ is continuous, it is uniformly continuous in $X=[a,b] \times [t_0-r,t_0+r]$. Therefore we have that $\exists \delta = \delta(t_0,\epsilon)$ s.t.
$$
\|(x,t)-(y,s)\|_2<\delta \implies |f(x,t)-f(y,s)|<\epsilon
$$
for $(x,t),(y,s) \in X$. Now let $h\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $|h|<\min\{r,\delta\}$. Then
\begin{equation}
|F(t_0+h) - F(t_0)| = \left|\int_a^b(f(x,t_0+h)-f(x,t_0))dx\right| \le (b-a)\epsilon 
\tag 1
\end{equation}
by using uniform continuity of $f$ in the integrand and noting that the arguments are less than $\delta$ apart.
Now, the part I am confused on is how this implies continuity of $F$ at $t_0$? I am slightly rusty on these topics.
I believe we can show $\lim_{h\to0}F(t_0+h)=F(t_0)$ and this is continuity of $F$ at $t_0$. How do I show this limit precisely from (1)? Intuitively my thoughts are that as $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small, $h$ also gets smaller as $\epsilon$ is small.

First of all you have a typo: $F(t_0+h,t_0)$ should just be $F(t_0+h)$. And second, you’ve shown that for every $\epsilon>0$, there’s a $\delta’>0$ such that for all $|h|<\delta’$, we have $|F(t_0+h)-F(t_0)|\leq (b-a)\epsilon$.
This is one of the many equivalent ways of defining continuity of $F$ at $t_0$. If you’re worried about the final inequality being $\leq (b-a)\epsilon$ rather than $<\epsilon$, then that’s a simple exercise in analysis for you to figure out (there are loads of proofs online; see also this MSE answer of mine for about 12 different ways of saying something is a limit).

Thanks. I understand clearly $(b-a)\epsilon$, not worried about that. My question is how to show this definition you've given is equivalent to the more standard definition. That definition being: $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta>0 s.t. \forall t\in\mathbb{R}, |t-t_0|<\delta \implies |F(t)-F(t_0)|<\epsilon$.

Also, is it rigorous enough to say that from $(1)$ that we have $\lim_{h\to0} |F(t_0+h)-F(t_0)| \le (b-a)\epsilon$?. Then since $\epsilon$ arbitrary we must have equality, that is, continuity of $F$.

If $\epsilon$ is a positive number, then so is $\epsilon/2(b-a)$. Use this positive number in the definition of limits, to get a $\delta>0$ such that … Anyway this is a much more basic exercise than showing continuity of an integral; read the link and try to prove the various equivalences. Atleast try to prove one or two of them. If you really can’t then search closely on the site.

It’s not rigorous if you write $\lim\limits{h\to 0}$, because how do you know the limit even exists? If you want to argue in this manner, you would have to use $\limsup\limits_{h\to 0}$, and then after that take the limit $\epsilon\to 0^+$ (i.e squeeze theorem), and only then can you conclude  the limit $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}$ exists and equals $0$. This approach with $\limsup$ is convenient but for here it’s overkill… you really should prove the 12 equivalences in the link before seriously moving on with analysis.

I see. So I understand clearly I have shown that $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta>0$ s.t. $\forall h\in\mathbb{R}, |h|<\delta \implies |F(t_0+h)-F(t_0)| < \epsilon$.
And so this is equivalent to $$
\forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta>0 \text{s.t.} \forall t\in\mathbb{R}, |t-t_0|<\delta \implies |F(t)-F(t_0)| < \epsilon.
$$
?.

Oh yes those are equivalent too (so now that gives us atleast 24 ways of describing limits).

Perfect, thanks. I understood this proof clearly and was just unneccesarily confused on this small part as I hadn't before seen this definition of continuity in a proof before.

Well, it’s all part of an analyst’s toolbox, and now you know it :)

Also, I was already aware of those 12 equivalences you had linked, I understood this part clearly. As you can see my problem was simply realising that what I had shown was a reformulation of the equivalent 'standard' definition of continuity. This is separate to what you attached in the link. I don't think I would have made it this far without knowing those.
